# Как передать переменную обработчику во фрейме?

Tags: php

Есть страница. На этой странице из базы извлекается поле и помещается в переменную. Можно ли как-то эту переменную передать странице, находящейся во фрейме этой же страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменную можно передать во фрейм используя стандартные $_POST и/или $_GET например.
Ну на крайняк куки, сессии.